# Using LIKE with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to PHP and database management, but I'm picking it up pretty quickly.
I'm trying to create a search bar, I have the searchbar working it just doesn't quite return the results I would like.
Essentially, I want to look for a film in my database based on its title (name), subtitle and release date. 
Here's the code I currently have:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $resultArray = '';
    $searchTerm = $_POST['searchTerm']; 
    if($getSearchResults = $conn->query("SELECT type, name, subtitle, release_date, poster_url, slug FROM media WHERE (name OR subtitle OR release_date) LIKE '%$searchTerm%' LIMIT 5")){   
        $resultArray = array();
        while($data = $getSearchResults->fetch_assoc()){            
            $resultArray[] = $data;                 
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No Data';
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray); 
}
```

This (likely obviously) doesn't work. If the field is empty the returned search results are all the films without a subtitle because that field is empty. However, if I type in a film name, like Avengers, or a release date, like 2018, nothing comes up. It literally only works for the blank fields for some reason?

Ultimately I'd just like your help getting this to return results LIKE the search term, I can live with it searching for blank fields, but if you have a solution for that too then - great!

Thanks

Comment: You've got an answer of MHewison, however, pay attention that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Mind the SQL injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do the following.

```
SELECT type, name, subtitle, release_date, poster_url, slug 
  FROM media 
    WHERE name LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR subtitle LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR release_date LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I should be noted that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not really make sense, as it will not produce predictable results.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, and also added ORDER BY as GMB suggested, but it's still not returning any results for some reason, not even the empty field results I was getting before...

Comment: Mind the SQL injections, crackers/hackers would love seeing this code to be used for real..

Comment: @ConnorHandley : this query should give you the results you want. If not, then you have another issue out of the SQL code.

Comment: @GMB using `ORDER BY` on a non unique column can also give predictable results for that matter, ideally you should `ORDER BY <column>, <primary key>`

Comment: Hey, you were right, it was my tacked-on ORDER BY that was breaking it. This was the correct answer and my search function now works. I'm going to try a few ORDER BY options and try to get most relevant results, starting with your suggestion @RaymondNijland . Thanks for all your help! re: the sql injections, do you have some documentation for this so I can look into it, I'm not sure what the risks are or how to counter such a thing.

Comment: " I'm not sure what the risks are" Well [SQL injection example (post off me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809948/mariadb-sql-injection/54810875#54810875) "or how to counter such a thing. " see [PHP prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).. Mine example is pretty "riskless" but it can be used to read data in anny table where the MySQL user has access, And or (blindly) bruteforce geuss (MySQL/Application) admin/users password hashes