# SQL injection - force execute second query if first one fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, execute

```
$query = 'SELECT EX1 AS date,rate FROM rates WHERE 
PARAM1="' . $param1 . '" and param2="' . $param2 . '" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1';
```

$param1 is vulnerable for SQLI - but there is a problem:
the query fails because `rates` doesn't exists - is it possible to inject another query , for ex:
 `` DROP TABLE `users ``
, after the query - even if the first fails to execute?

Comment: would this ever be a real-life scenario? Would you ever try executing SQL for a table that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes. see: https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/
Can you give us more information, what problem are you trying to solve? Use prepared statements.

Comment: *"for ex: DROP TABLE `users , after the query - even if the first fails to execute?"* Most likely no... @freeek   PHP MySQL clients do not support multiple SQL statements separated by semicon ..  There is a exception -> [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: *"$query = 'SELECT EX1 AS date,rate FROM rates WHERE 
PARAM1="' . $param1 . '" and param2="' . $param2 . '" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1';$param1 is vulnerable for SQLI - but there is a problem: the query fails because rates doesn't exists -"* ...  for SQL injection to work you would have to have a valid working query to attack..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MariaDb SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809948/mariadb-sql-injection)

Comment: That duplicate (post of me) will give a beginners tutorial how to test and attack which SQL injection MariaDB and MySQL based RDMS

Answer (score -1):

You should use PDO or mysqli to  bind param. Please view instruction [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or
[mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: This is not my question.