# Prove Sql Vulnerability

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP form vulnerable to MySQL injection, but I am trying to exploit it to prove it exists but I keep getting a syntax error

I tried doing this ', '', '', '', '', ''); UPDATE enrolment SET year = 2000 WHERE student_id = 's01'; --

but I got an SQL error

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully <br> <br>"; 



$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
$input2 = $_POST['input2'];
$input3 = $_POST['input3'];
$input4 = $_POST['input4'];
$input5 = $_POST['input5'];
$input6 = $_POST['input6'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (student_id, first_name, last_name, DOB, sex, phone) VALUES ('$input1', '$input2', '$input3', '$input4', '$input5', '$input6')";

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?><br><br>

Input 1  <?php echo $_POST["input1"]; ?><br>
Input 2  <?php echo $_POST["input2"]; ?><br>
Input 3  <?php echo $_POST["input3"]; ?><br>
Input 4  <?php echo $_POST["input4"]; ?><br>
Input 5  <?php echo $_POST["input5"]; ?><br>
Input 6  <?php echo $_POST["input6"]; ?>

  <p>
  <a href="/index.html">Return to the form</a>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Getting a SQL error is how you discover a vulnerability. From there you need to exploit it. There's innumerable sources on how to do this if you care to look deeper.

Comment: *"Getting a SQL error is how you discover a vulnerability. From there you need to exploit it. There's innumerable sources on how to do this if you care to look deeper. "* to add to @tadman 's comment..  i also once posted in the past a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809948/mariadb-sql-injection/54810875#54810875) on stackoverflow which explains it or advice on how to do SQL injections testing..